# Remove invalid characters from the href="tel:" attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, tel

I have a HTML5 telephone link:

```
<a href="tel:+44 (0) 1234 567 890">
```

Currently, the `href` attribute is getting the data from a field in the CMS, which I can't edit. I know that the number format is not correct as the telephone link leads to an error page when tapped/clicked.

I want the `href` attribute to be written like this so it is compatible with all mobile devices:

```
<a href="tel:+441234567890">
```

How can I use jQuery to remove the spaces and `(0)` characters from the `href` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to fix all links whose href starts with `tel:` :

```
$('a[href^="tel:"]').attr('href', function(_,v){
    return v.replace(/\(0\)|\s+/g,'')
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/rofot/1/edit)

This uses the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function taking a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as parameter. The regex I use can be understood like this :

- `\(0\)` : "(0)" with parenthesis escaped
- `|` : or
- `\s+` : at least one space

The `g` flag at the end of the regex makes it apply more than once.

So it replaces `(0)` or spaces with an empty string.

Comment: Missing a semicolon on one line there.

Comment: @SeanKendle It's a matter of style. You may add it if you want but it's not really needed.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Could you briefly explain what the code after `v.replace` is doing? - I can't make much sense out of the characters...

Comment: @user1794295 I extended my answer to explain

Comment: @dystroy excellent - very clear and easy to understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var l=$("a[href^='tel:']");
l.attr("href",l.attr("href").replace(/\s+/g,'').replace("(0)", ""));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3a7Gw/)